# Find next missing number in list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a very simple login script to learn about accessing files and lists but I'm a bit stuck.

```
newaccno = str(1)
with open("C:\\Python\\Test\\userpasstest.txt","r+") as loginfile:
    for line in loginfile.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        logininfo = line.split(" ")
        print(newaccno in logininfo[0])
    while newaccno in logininfo[0]: #issue is here, also tried ==
        newaccno += 1
        print(newaccno)
    loginfile.write(newaccno)
```

My logic is that it will search `logininfo[0]` for `newaccno` and if it is true, increase newaccno by 1 and search again until it is false then write to file (so if the file has 1, 2 and 3 already then newaccno will end up as 4).

Edit: This is how the txt file looks, the first number represents newaccno before it gets split.

```
1 abc qwe
2 123 456
```

Comment: What error or unexpected output are you getting?

Comment: It just skips the while loop altogether,  it thinks that at no point newaccno == logininfo[0]

Comment: I think the problem is in the line below, where you try to add an `int` to a `str. Try `newaccno = str(int(newaccno) + 1)` instead.

Comment: Same issue, it just ignores the while loop completely.

Comment: Well, after the loop, `logininfo` will be the last line in the file, and thus compare only to any numbers in that line. Is this intentional?

Comment: You should show an example of how your `userpasstest` file looks like.

Comment: If the last line of the input is empty, there won't be a space to split on, logininfo will be `None` and the while loop will be skipped. In this case `logininfo[0]` won't be a valid access, since `logininfo` cannot be indexed.

Comment: userpasstest format has been added, last line isn't empty.

Comment: Does your text file start with a line who's first character is `1`? If not, your while loop will never execute. (I know in your example it does, but want to make sure that the real file also matches this case)

Comment: Hold up, is it a formatting issue, or is your `while` loop really not inside your `for` loop? It needs to be inside for it to work. If it is outside `logininfo[0]` will always be the last line's first character.

Comment: oh... I didn't think it worked like that. TY very much. I don't know how to mark this as solved.

Comment: I can add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(adapted from comment)

Your `while` loop needs to be inside your `for` loop for it to work. If it is outside `logininfo[0]` will always be the last line's first character